# ROS1 Subscriber callback

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a simple class as follows:

```
class SimpleSub {
public:
    SimpleSub(ros::NodeHandle *nh) {
           nh->subscribe("/imu", 1000, &SimpleSub::imuSubsCallback, this);
   }
  void imuSubsCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr& msg)
  {
      ROS_INFO("Orientation: X=%f, Y=%f, Z=%f\n", msg->orientation.x, msg->orientation.y, msg->orientation.z);
  }
private:
       ros::Subscriber imuSub_;
};
```

When I run IMU publisher, my callback does not get called. However, it works when I use just stand-alone (not class member function)  like this:

```
void imuSubsCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr& msg);
```

There is no compile error. Am I doing something wrong when registering callback (nh->subscriber)?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352931/ros1-subscriber-callback/) by [fiji3119](https://answers.ros.org/users/53083/fiji3119/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-05-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to use `imuSub_` to subscribe, otherwise the subscription goes out of scope when you leave your constructor.

```
imuSub_= nh->subscribe("/imu", 1000, &SimpleSub::imuSubsCallback, this);
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2020-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fiji3119](https://answers.ros.org/users/53083/fiji3119/) on 2020-05-22**:
Duh! Yeah. Thank you for pointing that out. Works!